# Disable map drag on mouse drag for google map using flash api

Tags: flash-cs3

i want to disable the map drag when user try to drag the map
i am using flash cs3 and Google map api.
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method:

> map.disableDragging();